# AngularJS watch model of input type url

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

Watching the model of a url input doesn't work.

```
not working: <input name="url" type="url" ng-model="login.url" required>
             $scope.$watch('login.url', change);

working: <input name="text" type="text" ng-model="login.text" required>
         $scope.$watch('login.text', change);
```

I'm using the Ionic-Framework with AngularJS.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/y31yhu1v/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. You have specified the type as URL `type="url`, so it expects URL input. Something like http://example.com as input in that field will work. If you change the type to text `type="text` it will work just like the other field.

Answer (score 2):

If you put type="url", it automatically starts validating it as url, so unless you enter a proper url, the value remains unchanged in $scope variable. Try entering a valid url and you will see the event fired.